# Jquery: foreach through html block elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have html blocks and there would be many this kind of html block with different html values and image sources.

```
<div class="customers__photo" data-id="a1">

    <div class="infoblock infoblock-hidden">
        <div  class="infoblock__user-name"><strong>Alexander</strong></div> 
        <div  class="infoblock__date">21 August 2022</div>                       
        <div  class="infoblock__text">Comportable table</div>
    </div>      
    <img src="girl1.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
</div>
```

I want to extract all html values as array and I will console.log all values, sources with Jquery.

```
img_array =$(this).closest('.customers__content').find('.infoblock__user-name, .infoblock__date, .infoblock__text, img').map(function() {return 
        let name = $(".infoblock__user-name").html();
        let date = $(".infoblock__date").html();
        let text = $(".infoblock__text").html();                  
        $("img").attr("src")
    }).get();          
         
  img_array.forEach(function(name, date, text, src) {
        console.log(name, date, text, src);
    //$(".listblock").append(<img  class="listblock__photo" src="${src}">);
  });
```

I want to get all class values as i got for source of image (for (infoblock__user-name, infoblock__date, infoblock__text, )) using one foreACH. PLEASE HOW CAN i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax to implement `map()` isn't correct. You need to return an object, and the properties of that object need to be key/value pairs.

You also need to retrieve the values from the DOM relative to the current `.customers__photo` element in the DOM, not by selecting *all* instances of that class.

Try this:

```js
const data = $('.customers__photo').map((i, el) => ({
  name: $(el).find('.infoblock__user-name').text(),
  date: $(el).find('.infoblock__date').text(),
  text: $(el).find('.infoblock__text').text(),
  src: $(el).find('.reviews__photo').prop('src'),
})).get();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customers__photo" data-id="a1">
  <div class="infoblock infoblock-hidden">
    <div class="infoblock__user-name"><strong>Alexander</strong></div>
    <div class="infoblock__date">21 August 2022</div>
    <div class="infoblock__text">Comportable table</div>
  </div>
  <img src="girl1.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
</div>
<div class="customers__photo" data-id="a1">
  <div class="infoblock infoblock-hidden">
    <div class="infoblock__user-name"><strong>John</strong></div>
    <div class="infoblock__date">22 August 2022</div>
    <div class="infoblock__text">Expandable table</div>
  </div>
  <img src="girl2.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
</div>
<div class="customers__photo" data-id="a1">
  <div class="infoblock infoblock-hidden">
    <div class="infoblock__user-name"><strong>Edward</strong></div>
    <div class="infoblock__date">23 August 2022</div>
    <div class="infoblock__text">Collapsable table</div>
  </div>
  <img src="girl3.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
</div>
```